How to render VertexLabels and EdgeLabels with LaTeX style?
I have installed MaTeX and it works fine. Now I want to use it in Graph.
Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3}, VertexLabels -> {1 -> Placed["x^2", {1/2, 1/2}], 2 -> Placed["y^2", {1/2, 1/2}], 3 -> Placed["z^2", {1/2, 1/2}]}, VertexSize -> 1/4, EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> Placed["1/s", {1/2, {1/2, -1/2}}], 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> Placed["s/(s^2+1)", {1/2, {1/2, -1/2}}]}, VertexStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[None]]]


It does not work if I replace "x^2" with MaTeX["x^2"] or Style["x^2", MaTeX].
How should I correct the code? I want to achieve something like this


It does not work if I replace "x^2" with MaTeX["x^2"]  Did you install MaTeX?  Style["x^2", MaTeX]  That is not valid usage.

You can just remove "" and set BaseStyle:
Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3}, 
 VertexLabels -> {1 -> Placed[x^2, {1/2, 1/2}], 
   2 -> Placed[y^2, {1/2, 1/2}], 3 -> Placed[z^2, {1/2, 1/2}]}, 
 VertexSize -> 1/4, 
 EdgeLabels -> {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2 -> 
    Placed[1/s, {1/2, {1/2, -1/2}}], 
   2 \[DirectedEdge] 3 -> Placed[s/(s^2 + 1), {1/2, {1/2, -1/2}}]}, 
 VertexStyle -> Directive[FaceForm[None]], 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[14, FontFamily -> Times]]


